# excel vba: Summing values in a row only when column heading meets a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet where sales data is interspersed with other data in columns N:AD. The column headings for sales always end with the word Sales (e.g., "2015-06-Sales". I would like the data to sum for each row only when the heading ends in the word "Sales". I need to do this with vba because the column names will vary over time.

Example data (I want column F to sum the columns that end in sales - or N and P in the case below):

```
       Column F     Column N        Column O     Column P
       Total Sales  2015-05-Sales   2015-05-Qty  2015-01-Sales
Item1    20            5               30            15   
Item2    15            5               1             10  
Item3    10            1               2             9
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub test()
Dim lcolumn As Long
Dim lrow As Long
Dim SSold

For lrow = 2 To 100 Step 1
    For lcolumn = 14 To 30 Step 1
        If Right(ws.Range(1 & lcolumn), 5).Value = "Sales" Then
            SSold = 0
            SSold = SSold + Range(lrow & lcolumn)
        End If
    Next lcolumn
    Range(lrow & 6).Value = SSold
Next lrow

End Sub
```

It creates Run time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed on the line that starts "If right(range...

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Swap out `Range(lrow & lcolumn)` for `Cells(lrow, lcolumn)` in a couple of places. The [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) takes numerical parameters for the row and column. The [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) expects an xlA1 style cell reference.

Comment: I'm also wondering why you keep resetting `SSold = 0` everytime you find a match. It seems like ti will never collect a total; only the last matching value.

Comment: @Jeeped Isn't the OP resetting value for each column total?

Comment: @mrbungle - Maybe I'm just not reading that correctly but it seems to me that `SSold` is reset to zero immediately before adding any new value into itself.

Comment: `SSold` is going to retain that value each time and just keep adding to itself instead of resettting to 0 to total each column.  Also setting to zero from the begining is the way I'd do it.  I've expierenced excel hold on to a value from a previous run of the code.

Comment: I think you are both right - Paulo's solution below did exactly what I wanted it to... he also changed the placement of my "SSold" - see where total is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Sub SumSales()
    Dim total As Double

    For iRow = 2 To 100      'no need of Step 1, test as many rows as you wish
        total = 0            'resets the total for each row
        For iCol = 14 To 30  'tests as many columns as you wish
            If Right(Cells(1, iCol).Value, 5) = "Sales" Then
                total = total + Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
            End If
        Next iCol            'this loop will go on for each column in iRow row
        Cells(iRow, 6).Value = total  'store the total before going to the next row
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Range takes "A2" style range definitions. Range(Column, Row)

```
If Right(ws.Range("A" & lrow), 5).Value = "Sales" Then
```

Try cells if you need to use a number. Cells(row, column)

```
If Right(ws.Cells(1 & lcolumn), 5).Value = "Sales" Then
```